# how does the mp3 search engines work?

Tags: search, mp3, search-engine

for example:
http://mp3monkey.net

does everybody know how does this site work in the back-end those kind of sites?

so, more accurate question:
how to search the internet for mp3 files with some parameters like name?

Regards,
Paweł

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they use a searching algorithm, ehich you can find many or you can implement one on your own. I would suggest writing your question better for better responses!